# Opening a file from Toast Notification

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

In my UWP app I am downloading a file and storing it in the location chosen by the user using `FolderPicker`. When the download has completed, I show a ToastNotification. I am using these two namespaces as shown in the docs.

```
using Microsoft.QueryStringDotNET; // for receciving arguments
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
```

the toast that I send has two buttons, 1) open the file 2) Dismiss.
I want to open the downloaded file when the user taps on the first button.

But from what I understand, toasts can only send string arguments to the application ( Correct me if wrong ). And in order to open a file, `StorageFile` object is needed ( path of `StorageFile` won't do ).

So is there any way to actually open the downloaded file from the toast ( using foreground or background activation ) ?

Code to download the file:

```
private async void DownloadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    StorageFolder selectedFolder;   
    try
    {
        selectedFolder = await ChooseFolderAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        Toast.ShowToast("Something went wrong", ToastRow);
        return;
    }

    Uri downloadLink = new Uri("ValidUri");    

    StorageFile destinationFile = await selectedFolder.CreateFileAsync(selectedAsset.name, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
    downloader.SuccessToastNotification = handler.MakeToastWithButtons("Downloaded", selectedAsset.name, "Open", "Dismiss");
   // downloader.SuccessToastNotification = handler.MakeToast("Downloaded", nameOfFile, string.Empty, 2);
    DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(downloadLink, destinationFile);
    download.Priority = BackgroundTransferPriority.High;
    download.CostPolicy = BackgroundTransferCostPolicy.Always;    

    var toast = handler.MakeToast("Downloading...", selectedAsset.name, selectedAsset.contentSize, 12);
    toast.Group = "downloadStartedTag";
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);

    Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(handler.DownloadProgress);

    try
    {
        await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);       
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var errorCode = BackgroundTransferError.GetStatus(ex.HResult);
        toast = handler.MakeToast("Download failed", selectedAsset.name, TextFormatter.CamelToHumanCase(errorCode.ToString()), 12);
        toast.Group = "downloadFailedTag";
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);

        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove("downloadStartedTag");
    }   
}
```

Method that creates toast:

```
public ToastNotification MakeToastWithButtons(string heading, string line1, string button1, string button2)
{
    ToastVisual visual = new ToastVisual()
    {
        BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
        {
            Children =
            {
                new AdaptiveText() {Text = heading},
                new AdaptiveText() {Text = line1},
            }
        }
    };

    ToastActionsCustom actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
    {
        Buttons =
        {
            new ToastButton("Open", new QueryString()
            {
                { "action", "open" }
                //maybe file path can be given here in some argument

            }.ToString())
            {
                ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Foreground
            },

            new ToastButton("Dismiss", new QueryString()
            {
                { "action", "dismiss" }
                //more details about the file can be given here

            }.ToString())
            {
                ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background
            }                        
        }

    };

    ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
    {
        Visual = visual,
        Actions = actions,

        // Arguments when the user taps body of toast
        Launch = new QueryString()
        {
            { "action", "nothing" }
        }.ToString()
    };

    // And create the toast notification
    var toast = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml());
    toast.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
    toast.Group = "DownloadCompleteGroup";

    return toast;
}
```

Comment: Your toast is related to your app but not the file that you downloaded. So when you tap open, it will still need to redirect back to your app and then you can use the file path and open the file.

Comment: how can I open a file with just the filepath? I thought I would need a `StorageFile` ( which I don't think I can pass through the toast )

Comment: Can you post the code you use to download, and the code you use to show the toast? There are several options and knowing which is best depends on the code you already have.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to store the `destinationFile` created by the background download in the [`FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions), which will provide you with a `token` you can add to the payload data of the toast:

```
// using Windows.Storage.AccessCache;
string token = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(destinationFile);
// add the token to your toast payload
```

Then when the user clicks the toast, you can redeem the `token` to get the file back:

```
var file = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(token);
```

Now you can do things with the file. Note that the token is good "forever" - as long as the file exists on disk, the token will work after your app restarts or even a reboot.

When you are done with the file (including if the download fails or the user cancels, etc.) you should remove the token from `FutureAccessList` so that the list doesn't fill up:

```
StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Remove(token);
```

This means you likely want to persist the token in your app's settings as well, just in case the user ignores the toast.